# setState not working in react native after fetching data from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

It is my first day with react native, I am working with mangodb, I stored record in db and fetched record, now I want to show in flatlist, and need to setState() but it throws error of undefined

```
db.find({}, function (err, docs) {
      this.setState({ dataSource: docs });   
});
```

docs is array of users and I am able to print data in console, its working, but problem is how do I set this data in datasource using setState.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's related to the way you call setState. `this` inside the context of your function is not pointing to the component class. One way to solve it is to use an arrow function:

```
db.find({}, (err, docs) => {
      this.setState({ dataSource: docs });   
});
```

If you can't use arrow functions, you can do the binding of your function to the outside context manually:

```
function cb (err, docs) {
      this.setState({ dataSource: docs });   
}

db.find({}, cb.bind(this));
```

The logic behind `this` keyword in javascript is discussed in detail in this question: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) Or in this amazing book by Kyle Simpson: [YDKJS: this & object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)